# Updating my nuget packages in ASP.Net MVC breaks my project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nuget-package

I updated my nuget packages in my ASP.Net MVC application and now I have a ton of errors when building. It looks like some relate to HTML Helpers.

[image]

Here is what it says in the error list for one of the errors.
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"